# IR2118 No High side signal - Weird behavior when fed 12V on VCC Pin

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, mosfet-driver

[IRS2104](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir2117.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c84331168d)

I'm trying to get this working from the datasheet and I've also [read all of this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-HV_Floating_MOS_Gate_Drivers-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626c1f3dc3016c47de609d140a&redirId=114085) trying to pull this together and I get very strange results.

I have a 47 uF cap from VCC to COM per the docs. I have VCC as 12 VDC. I have IN powered by a PWM pin from an Arduino that is definitely working (scoped it and it's doing what it should) Com is to negative from the 12 VDC power supply

I have a diode between VCC and VB and another 47 uF cap between VB and VS per the schematic.

HO PWMs nicely if there is no 12 VDC power supply and the to it. As soon as I put the 12 VDC to VCC I just got noise and the FET doesn't turn on at all. I've tried with and without the Arduino connected to GND/12VDC Negative and get the same results.

Weirdly, I have a low side MOSFET that is connected to a inverted PWM 5 V pin on the Arduino. I accidently disconnected that but still has my scope hooked up, and the gate was showing power on it at the same square as the high side gate. (They're connected at the floating center from drain of the low side to source of the high side.) As soon as the pin was connected again, the gates were properly in opposition with dead time as I'd programmed.

I'm using 44Ns for the MOSFETs and have verified that on the low side that the Arduino will turn on the FET.

What am I doing wrong? It seems like this should be trivial but I'm clearly screwing something up and at wit's end.

Here's the circuit that I'm copying (which I didn't think I needed, but since I'm getting weird results...).  This is for the H Bridge version with IR2110 which I also have, and also has the same issue.

[image: Half Bridge]

And I'm using the values from here:

[image]

With no voltage on Vb or Vcc Hin, Ho are same square wave PWM at whatever duty cycle I set. Lo, Lin same in opposition to Hin, Ho. If I disconnect Lin then Lo has the same PWM as Hin/Ho. As soon as I apply 12V to VCC and VB (after the diode) then Hin and Lin stay as the proper PWM and HO and LO go flat line at 11.85 (diode losses), the gates open, and it creates a dead short.

Comment: A schematic would be really nice. You can add one in **using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar**. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and **Save and Insert** on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Post oscillograms of Vb, Ho, Hin, Lo, Lin and Vcc.